# Spatial Index Query in php

Tags: php, mysql, spatial-query

I'm trying to write a query in PHP for a spatial index. But I'm having trouble writing the query for the following line of code...

```
SET @p = CONCAT('Polygon((',lat1,'',lon1,',',lat1,'',lon2,',',lat2,'',lon2,',',lat2,'',lon1,',',lat1,'',lon1,'))');
```

Comment: If you specify what you are trying to accomplish, you may get an answer. This is too vague at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

if you use mysql extension in php , this query returned to error. if use mysql extension , please use mysqli extension

Answer (score 0):

The generally correct order (with a few odd exceptions) is `(long lat)`, not `(lat long)`.  Or are you just missing a space in your concat between `lat1 long1`?  The WKT syntax is:

`GeomFromText('POLYGON(long1 lat1, long2 lat2, long3 lat3)')`

Coordinates are separated by a space, points by a comma.  There *may* even be a case sensitivity problem, though the spec is case insensitive, it is best to use `ALL CAPS`, and I have gotten errors that I think were related to case.